# Ubuntu 20.04 No wireless extensions

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, amd-graphics

I did a dual-boot with Ubuntu 20.04 and since i did it, i can only have internet with Ethernet.

So I searched some issues on internet but nothing that I found worked.

Then:

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:3041]
    Kernel modules: 8821ce, rtl8821ce
05:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Picasso [1002:15d8] (rev c2)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Picasso [1043:18f1]
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`iwconfig`:

```
br-6524119a49b6  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp2s0    no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

`sudo modprobe rtl8821ce && dmesg | grep -i rtl`:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8821ce': Device or resource busy
```

`lsmod | grep 8821` produced no output.